# double click/click-drag-release on terminal to select a text results CTRL-C

Tags: xterm, double-click, linux-terminal

When I `double-click` in a terminal, for example xterm, konsole, to select text, it'll select text and **then the cursor** `return`. It's not expected because the cursor should be not be moved. I meet this behavior only today after I re-installed Windows 7. I use Citrix to access remote host and never came across this behavior before.

Edit 3: Close inspection show that it's a `CTRL-C` signal sent to the term. That's why it so annoying because when you double click or click-drag/release accidentally in that term, the program you ran in foreground will be killed...

Edit 2: update: I found that even doulbe click outside of terminal or click somewhere, drag a little bit and then release will do the same effect.

Edit 1: If I use putty to login the server directly from windows, this behavior doesn't happen. So I suspect this has something to do with the xterm/konsole or other terminal.

Please help since I double-click here and there to select text so frequently that a return will interrupt the whole process. Thanks.

System Info: X.org 6.8.3(192)

Answer (score 1):

If you use QTranslate, it will also happen if mouse mode is enabled.
To disable it, right click on QTranslate in the systray, and disable "Mouse mode"

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by one translator software YoDaoDict(Chinese name: 有道). It'll translate the word/sentences you select(or pointed by cursor as you config) on your screen, which somehow mess up with my terminal. After I quitted the software, all symptom disappeared. It's a good software, though this minor flaw bug me for a really long time.

The solution I temporarily use it to close the translation-by-select function while I worked in Citrix session(caused I don't need any translation there); and when I browse webpage, I simply activate that function by using a hot-key.

Answer (score 0):

set "Enable mouse mode only when Ctrl is pressed" from Options Advanced.

Comment: Welcome to superuser; This could provide a solution to the question but a little detail and presentation it would reach beginners it is  best suited to comment.,,,,yes  once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. again welcome to superuser and keep coming back.